# Second normal form does not produce the desired result

Tags: database-design

I have a problem with 2NF and I have been unable to solve it by using Google. It is making me crazy because I am a teacher and I don't want to teach wrong stuff to my students.

Let's have a table with 5 fields.

*Gradings = {StudentName, SubjectCode, SubjectName, #Exam, Grade}*

Dependencies are this way:

*StudentName, SubjectCode, #Exam -> Grade*

*SubjectCode -> SubjectName*

*SubjectName -> SubjectCode*

Therefore, candidate key 1 is *{StudentName, SubjectCode, #Exam}* and candidate key 2 is *{StudentName, SubjectName, #Exam}*.

Prime attributes are *{StudentName, SubjectCode, SubjectName, #Exam}* and non-prime attributes is *Grade*

According to the definition of second normal form, a non-prime attribute cannot depend on a part of a candidate key. The only non-prime attribute (Grade) does not depend on a part of a candidate key so this table seems in 2NF .

The problem is that I think something is amiss (and I could be wrong). I think subjects should have their own table.

*Gradings = {StudentName, Subject Code, #Exam, Grade}*

*Subjects = {Subject Code, SubjectName}*

But 2NF does not produce this. 3NF is about dependencies between non-prime attributes so it does not produce this either. But it seems to me that this is the right outcome, because it has no redundancy.

I guess if non-prime attribute was defined as "attribute that is not a candidate key", 2NF would produce the desired result. But I have checked this again and again and non-prime attribute is defined as "attribute that does not BELONG to a candidate key".

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I am beating my head against a wall.

Thank you in advance.